# Schema for a list of links on a category list landing page?

Tags: schema.org, navigation, categories

I have a page that is structured as `https://www.example.com/pages/category`.

On this page are three links:

1. `https://www.example.com/shop/mens`
2. `https://www.example.com/shop/womens`
3. `https://www.example.com/shop/kids`

The current schema I have for this page is structured as so:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "CollectionPage",
  "name": "Name of Page",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/pages/category",
  "description": "Description Goes Here",
  "mainContentOfPage": [
    {
        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
        "name": "Anchor Text of Category Link",
        "url": "URL of Category"
    },
    {
        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
        "name": "Anchor Text of Category Link",
        "url": "URL of Category"
    },
    {
        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
        "name": "Anchor Text of Category Link",
        "url": "URL of Category"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this correct? It validates with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Note that Schema.org terms are case-sensitive. It must be `mainContentOfPage` instead of `mainContentofPage`, and `SiteNavigationElement` instead of `siteNavigationElement`. I edited your question to fix these.

Comment: Did you move a bracket? That code only validates the CollectionPage, not the SiteNavigationElements.

Comment: Nope, my changes don’t seem to be responsible for this. [Your original version](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/revisions/121447/1) has the same issue. The problem is in line 7: the `}` needs to be removed. (I edited again to fix it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SiteNavigationElement`](https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement) is most likely meant to represent the whole navigation, not the single links the navigation consists of. To provide data about each link, you could use `SiteNavigationElement` together with an `ItemList` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52766577/1591669)).

That said, I’m not convinced that `mainContentOfPage` and `SiteNavigationElement` are suitable for conveying what the page means. The links in question seem to be the content of the page, they are not the site navigation (which is typically in the header).

A pretty basic solution could be using [`significantLink`](https://schema.org/significantLink), but this only allows specifying the URL, not the name:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "CollectionPage",
  "name": "Name of Page",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/pages/category",
  "description": "Description Goes Here",
  "significantLink": [
    "https://www.example.com/shop/mens",
    "https://www.example.com/shop/womens",
    "https://www.example.com/shop/kids"
  ]
}
```

A more expressive solution could be using `mainEntity` (if the three links really are the main content of that page) with an `ItemList`:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "CollectionPage",
  "name": "Name of Page",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/pages/category",
  "description": "Description Goes Here",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement": [
      {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "name": "Anchor Text of Category Link",
        "url": "URL of Category"
      },
      {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "name": "Anchor Text of Category Link",
        "url": "URL of Category"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```